# How to store Search History

Tags: java, database-design, lucene, backend

I am building a set of 'Now-Trending' kind of visualizations to showcase the trending searches/ trending documents within my system. The idea to show the top queries that came to my system/ most viewed results etc.

I was wondering what would be the most effective and scalable Java based backend for this. If it's a database what should be the schema like? Or is it wise to maintain this info within a Lucene index? Presently for the prototype I store them in a flat file in an unstructured format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try storing this kind of data in a key-value store such as [Redis](http://redis.io/). Redis has efficient atomic methods for incrementing counters that you can use for accruing votes for queries.

Answer (score 1):

A schema-less backend might be preferable if you plan on capturing data ad-hoc or are unsure of your data needs in the future. Additionally, a scalable solution (horizontally) would support growth in the dataset. With regards to your question about whether to store this data in a search engine, here's a great article going over that concept with some examples.

http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/2011/05/13/data-visualization-with-elasticsearch-and-protovis.html